# anonymous post Twitter, Facebook

Tags: twitter, facebook

Actually am doing shopping cart application ,

after good are transfered we are asking the feedback about our service ,

So customer will give the feedback, this feedback form contain the about our service , the ans are in the rating also we given an comment form , in that they writing something about our servce ,

So we have idea , that is post these good comment into twitter adn facebook,

But customer not showed much interest to login into twitter and then share the twits ,

So is there any way that without account post the twits ,

Thanks
Bharanikumar

How to post twit msg in twitter and facebook without account ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. You need an account to post on both Facebook and Twitter; anonymous posts are not allowed or even possible.

One suggestion might be to post these comments *from your account* saying a customer said X. But of course this has nothing to do with programming...

Answer (score 0):

Posting onto Facebook and Twitter without accounts is not possible.